# Validation Error not showing in django template

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

Everything works except for the fact that when there is invalid login, the validation error does not show. Any idea why this is so?

views.py

```
class LoginView(FormView):

    form_class = AccountAuthenticationForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        email = self.request.POST['email']
        password = self.request.POST['password']
        user = authenticate(email=email, password=password)
        auth_login(self.request, user)
        return redirect("HomeFeed:main")
        if not authenticate(email=email, password=password):
            raise forms.ValidationError("Invalid login")
```

forms.py

```
class AccountAuthenticationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(label='Password', widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        model = Account
        fields = ('email', 'password')

    def clean(self):
        if self.is_valid():
            email = self.cleaned_data['email']
            password = self.cleaned_data['password']
        else: 
            raise forms.ValidationError("Invalid login")
```

Comment: `form_valid` runs when the form was already *validated*. You thus should perform the validation in the `clean` method.

Comment: Plus it is best that you directly use the builtin [`LoginView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.LoginView) here. (It can work with custom user models regardless of different username field, etc.)